# Anomaly in Equation of State curves (P vs V) for graphite VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I'm new to DFT calculations and trying to produce the Equation of State curves (e.g. Pressure vs Volume) of Graphite. I started relaxing the system with ISIF=3 and then gradually scaled up and down the relaxed cell (with ISIF=4) in order to create the different points on the PV curve. However, my PV curve demonstrates abnormal spikes and I couldn't find out the issue. I was able to produce the PV curve for Diamond and it came out smoothly following the same procedure. Any advice is highly appreciated. I'm using PAW_PEB for carbon.

My INCAR for initial relaxation looks like this,

```
SYSTEM= C_graphite
PREC=  A
ENCUT= 400.0
EDIFF= 1e-6
IBRION= 2
ISIF= 3
NSW= 100
ISMEAR= 0 ; SIGMA = 0.05
ISTART=0
POTIM= 0.5
LCHARG= .FALSE.
LWAVE= .FALSE.
LREAL= .FALSE.
EDIFFG = -1e-2
ISYM=0
```

And POSCAR looks like this for Graphite,

```
C4
1.0
   1.2336456308015413   -2.1367369110836267    0.0000000000000000
   1.2336456308015413    2.1367369110836267    0.0000000000000000
   0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    7.8030730000000004
C
4
direct
   0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.2500000000000000 C
   0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.7500000000000000 C
   0.3333333333333333    0.6666666666666666    0.2500000000000000 C
   0.6666666666666667    0.3333333333333334    0.7500000000000000 C
```

I have used automatic k-point mesh as follows,

```
EA
0
Auto
  32
```

My PV curve looks like this and it definitely has an error,
[image]

Can you guys please advise me to find out my mistake?

Thank you very much.

Comment: plot results from ISIF=2 instead of 4 and check

Comment: Thank you @Pranavkumar. It worked. But I'm afraid about the restrictions imposed with ISIF=2 (the shape of the unit cell is held constant). could it affect the phase transitions that might take place with the compression/expansion of the system?

Comment: Are you expecting graphite to change in to diamond with ISIF=4?  Another point ISIF=4 is putting restrictions of keeping volume to be fixed whereas ISIF=2 is not considering any degree of freedom from simulation box. Hence minimization process is much difficult using ISIF=4

Comment: If Pranav's questions in the comments get ignored, the question can get closed as "abandoned". I'm not saying that this will happen, but it's something to consider.

Comment: @NikeDattani I'm kinda new to this and didn't know that.

Comment: @Pranavkumar Thanks for your reply, Yeah, I was expecting If I let the shape of the cell to be unconstrained, then such a phase transition could be occur. I'm not sure about it though. I'm just starting things here. Pardon me for the late reply.

Comment: Starting with certain symmetry it is difficult to achieve completely different symmetric structure. Phase transition is not possible as system is stuck in local minima or metastable structure.